# error in ruby on rails controller class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this sort of error, earlier it wored properly but some how it is the error.

```
      undefined method `save' for 2:Fixnum
```

And this my code in line_item_controller.rb/create

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to store_url}
      format.js   { @current_item = @line_item }
      format.json { render :json => @line_item, :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @line_item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

please help!

Comment: What does the method `add_product(id)` return? You call save on it later, that's probably where the error message is coming from.

Comment: would you please show the implementation of add_product it seems that it is returning some constant

Comment: here is the add_product implementation.  
def add_product(product_id)
current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
if current_item
current_item.quantity += 1
else
current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
end
end

Comment: You can edit your question - no need to paste code into a comment, where it is difficult to read

Comment: it's hard to read the code without formatting, but the line `current_item.quantity += 1` returns an integer value; if that's the last statement in the flow of control then that's the value that's returned from the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `add_product` method is returning an integer instead of the product you're expecting.

This means the `@line_item.save` is evaluating to `<some number>.save`, which is why you're getting the error.

Check `add_product` and make sure it returns the object instead of the id.

Comment: thanx Richard, I actually forgot to write the return value at the end, your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

`@cart.add_product` seems return a number (`Fixnum`) instead of a model object, as you expect. If you don't know how to fix that, show us implementation of `add_product`.